# how to make the link active in pdf when we render the visual force page as PDf?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, renderas

**apex page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity__c" extensions="OpportunityController" renderAs="pdf">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunities" collapsible="false">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opp}" var="op">
          <apex:column value="{!op.Name}"/> 
          <apex:column value="{!op.Parent_Account_Name__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!op.stage__c}"/>   
          <apex:column >
            <apex:commandLink value="Product Details" action="{!ProductDetails}">
              <apex:param name="recordId" value="{!op.id}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product List" collapsible="false">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!prd}" var="p">
          <apex:column value="{!p.Name}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.Date__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.Discount__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.List_Price__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.Opportunity__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.Product_Code__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.Quantity__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.Sales_Price__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.SubTotal__c}"/>
          <apex:column value="{!p.Total_Price__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**extension**

```
public with sharing class OpportunityController {
  public List<Opportunity__c> opp {get;set;}
  public List<Product__c> prd {get;set;}

  public OpportunityController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    opp=[select Name,Parent_Account_Name__c,stage__c from Opportunity__c ];
  }

  public PageReference ProductDetails() {
    id custId=(Id) ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('recordId');
    prd=[select id,Name,Date__c,Discount__c,List_Price__c,Opportunity__c,Product_Code__c,Quantity__c,Sales_Price__c,
    SubTotal__c,Total_Price__c from Product__c where Opportunity__c=:custId ];
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the documentation for [`<apex:commandLink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm), you will see that the `action` parameter invokes a server method using AJAX. You can't use Javascript in a PDF. The **[`<apex:outputLink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm)** tag, on the other hand, simply uses a URL. If you want a link that works in a PDF, use the latter.

Comment: should i need to create  java script for that link to be active in pdf?

Comment: I'll repeat...you cannot use Javascript in pdf pages.